# Instagram photo get path and save into database

Tags: php, javascript, tags, instagram

Hi I am currently doing my website to pull all instagram photo into my web.

this is my code:

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


 new Instafeed({ 
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'xxx',
        image_size: 'standard_resolution',
    }).run(); 



</script>
```

How do I get the url/path of the photo that i pulled inside my site?
Is it something about JSON? but i dont know what is it anyone can give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the [API](http://instagram.com/developer/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a webcrawler to pull the information you need from website.

[Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-basic-web-crawler-pull-information-website/) is a nice tutorial. You need to specify the url and the desired html tag.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find('img') as $link)
{
echo $link->href."<br />";
}
```

Moreover you should look over [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to improve you webcrawler.

EDIT:

> @youaremysunshine

the code above is from the tutorial i suggested you look at. 'simple_html_dom.php' is a file that you need to download (you can find it in the tutorial) in order to use its functions.
So, after you include the file, you simply create a `new simple_html_dom` object and call the function `load_file()` with the desired url as a parameter. `$html->find('img')` looks for the `<img>` tag from the given page. Try to read the tutorial a few times and you may need to look up for part 2. Go to the website with the desired image and inspect element to see wich element you need to use for the `find()` function (the parameter may also contain the class/id of the searched element).

Comment: Sorry I dont get it what you mean... can u explain more? Sorry for it Im just too new in this